# Is there a way to take a kloutId and get the user's profile page?

Tags: api, rest, twitter, klout

For example, I can take my twitter handle, mcmancsu and use www.klout.com/mcmancsu and get my profile page.  If I use the REST API to get my klout ID, is there a way to obtain my profile page based on the ID alone?  Alternatively, if I have a google+ ID how could I find the user's profile page (with/without kloutID)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the 'nick' field that is returned back from the user.json/[kloutid] endpoint can be used to build the profile URL.

Profiles URLs are in the format of: http://klout.com/user/[nick]

This will be true of users you've looked up by Twitter or Google+.

Alternatively, you can use the kloutId directly, but it's not preferred: http://klout.com/user/id/[kloutId]

Comment: Can you briefly elaborate why /user/id/kloutid is not preferred though?

Comment: It's not human readable and unnecessarily proliferates numeric IDs instead of screen names.